# Computer crashing after Windows update

Tags: windows, memory, crash

after my computer did a Windows 10 update, programs on my computer would randomly crash. I reverted the update and my computer worked normally again. Later, I updated Windows again because I wanted some new features, and my computer started crashing again.

To try to stop the crashes, I did a fresh installation of Windows on a different hard drive, reset the BIOS settings to default, and updated my drivers with the free version of Driver Booster, but the problem continues. I also did a RAM check with MemTest, but it found no errors.

Because the problem occurs on both hard drives, it likely isn't the hard drives' problem. MemTest didn't find errors; however, I remember that when I used MemTest a long time ago, it found errors, which is strange. So the RAM could be part of the problem?

Either way, I'm fairly certain there is a correlation between the Windows update and my computer problems.

A similar problem has happened before to this same computer a while ago, but I somehow fixed it. It could be related to the problems I'm having now. Any advice?

Comment: Maybe this is related: https://www.windowslatest.com/2020/04/19/windows-10-kb4549951-issues/

Comment: @vasili111 - That update is not the author's problem.

Answer (score 1):

Run OCCT memory stability test. Memtest will only find outright broken memory modules.

If it only happened after an update, it seems likely the update broke something. When you reinstalled, did you update to the latest version?

Comment: Yes, I updated to the latest version

Comment: Most likely a software bug introduced in the latest update, then.